# Spaces vs. Tabs - the sequel to the sequel to the sequel

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

There has been YAQASvsT (Yet Another Question About Spaces vs Tabs).
I spotted this particular question [*Do good reasons for using tabs or spaces for indentation exist?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186374/do-good-reasons-for-using-tabs-or-spaces-for-indentation-exist) on the [Recently Reopened list](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?s=1&tab=close&daterange=last30days) on the 10K mod tools page. That's right - it got closed and then *re-opened*.

Knowing that this question has been asked a billion times before, I went searching for a duplicate. But I couldn't find any, not using the SO Search, or Google (targeting SO). It seems we may have closed and deleted all questions relating to this topic - this is good, but I thought one of the previous questions may have been kept around simply to be used as the canonical answer. These were the only possible dupes I could find [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732324/spaces-vs-tabs-best-practice), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782426/c-spaces-vs-tabs?noredirect=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728226/using-tab-or-spaces-indentation-for-code), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717900/are-spaces-preferred-over-tabs-for-indentation) (3 of them are already deleted, 1 is closed with only a single answer).

So.... can someone dig up an old popular version of this question so the current one can be closed as a duplicate? Or at the very least can a moderator close it as a dupe of this (recent) question on Programmers.SE: [*Tabs versus spaces—what is the proper indentation character for everything, in every situation, ever?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaceswhat-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e)

Please can we make it go away, like, forever?

Comment: When spaces vs tabs questions get asked, a little piece of the internet dies, and rainbows turn to shades of grey. I shudder every time I see them.

Comment: But *what is the correct answer to the question*? I've searched high and low on the Internet, and somehow I can't find one

Comment: Spacetabs obviously.

Comment: Someone actually edited my question the other day and replaced the spaces with tabs and left a nastygram.  I don't even know how to *add* tabs to the editor without copying and pasting tabs from notepad or something...

Comment: @Pekka웃  If you have ever tried to edit code with a VT-100 over a 1200 baud modem, you know the answer.

Comment: I pressed tab once, and it turned out to be four spaces in disguise. They had killed and eaten the tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question should be closed as non constructive, in the same way it has been closed on Programmers.
The question on Programmers has been asked when Programmers was more permissive about the subjective questions that you could ask; now subjective questions on Programmers are allowed, but there are specific requirements.

Talking of the question on Stack Overflow, it is not a question asked because of an existing problem, but rather out of curiosity. It is one for which all the answers would be equally valid. Those are two reasons for which the question should not be asked on Stack Overflow (and other SE sites as well).